# deploying frontend and backend to the same web service on azure

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, typescript

i have a web app that has a seperate nodejs backend and angular frontend.

is it possible to make them both run on the same azure web service? or do i need a stand alone service for each?

my nodejs server is just a light API that feeds my angular app with some statistical data to render it. if it is possible what would be the way to do it?

since i am using typescript i know i need to push my nodejs using zipdeployment and i know i need to use visual studio to push my angular project to azure. but when i want to run both on the same service, how do i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it possible to make them both run on the same azure web service? or do i need a stand alone service for each?

If you choose the Web App on Windows OS, IIS allows you to configure multiple virtual applications within a single website. For this approach, you could follow [Deploying multiple virtual directories to a single Azure Website](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/). **Note:** The multiple virtual applications would share the same application pool.

As kim mentioned, **you pay for the App Service Plan, not for the Web App**. You could also host nodejs backend and angular frontend in different web apps under the same app service plan.

For the deployment, you could leverage VS publish wizard or manually upload your files via [KUDU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) or [FTP](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2014/08/01/microsoft-azure-web-site-connect-to-your-site-via-ftp-and-uploaddownload-files/). Moreover, you could also follow [Deploy the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-content-sync) section about various approaches for deployment.

Answer (score 5):

You can run multiple web sites in different web apps in Azure so that they are sharing the same Azure App Service.

You can think of the App Service as a virtual machine offering resources for your applications. How many web apps you can run simultaneously depends on the size of your plan, see [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/) page for details.

This way you can deploy them separately, manually or automatically using e.g. [VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/?view=vsts).