# How do I connect my Azure frontend static web app to my Azure backend app service via endpoints?

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-devops, postman, endpoint

For a learning project we've built a frontend and backend application. The frontend "application" is just a bunch of linked html/css/javascript files. The backend application is a spring boot / maven / java project with some endpoints.

When I run the backend application locally I am able to send a GET-request successfully using Postman. Now we've hosted the backend application via Azure and I have no idea how I can send a GET-request, I don't know which url to use.

After I get this to work I'd like to connect front- and backend application using these url's.

Answer (score 1):

As you can run the backend application in your local environment successfully, you have to follow the below steps to configure and deploy the spring boot web app to azure app service:

- In a terminal window, run the following command to configure your web app with the [Azure Maven Plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/blob/develop/azure-webapp-maven-plugin/README.md/)

`./mvnw com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.14.0:config`

- Then, at the Command Prompt, run this maven command and set the default configurations by typing **ENTER** and **Confirm (Y/N)** => **'y'** and the configuration will gets completed.
- Once you've done with the above steps, run
  `mvn azure-webapp:deploy` to publish the web app to Azure.
- Your webapp **URL** will be displayed in the output.

> I don't know which url to use?

You can use that URL from maven console output and access the web-app.

Also Refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49654580/deploying-frontend-and-backend-to-the-same-web-service-on-azure)  thread to know how to deploy frontend and backend to the same app service plan.